# C# importing csv file into SQL database using FileHelpers

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, filehelpers

i'm trying to import a .csv file using the great FileHelpers library.
Doing some research most of the time i read that i should use BulkCopy to import the result into an SQL database table.

Could you please help me how to accomplish this? So far i have this:

```
public void ImportCSV()
        {
            string path = @"C:\...\...\...\TestCSV\";
            var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Customer>();
            var result = engine.ReadFile(path + "test3.csv");

            engine.WriteFile(path + "FileOut.csv", result);
        }
```

and a mapping class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Feld1;
    public string Feld2;
    public string Feld3;
    public string Feld4;
}
```

this works but i don't know how instead of writing the result in a new .csv file i can use an SQL table (i know this has been discussed before but i can't find a solution that's working for me so far)
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: MySQL (is that what you mean by dbms?)

Comment: any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't directly read it into SQL.  You read it into a DataTable via the FileHelpers routines then use that DataTable to populate the database using whichever .NET provider you need to.